# Black dot of Death SQL potential issue

Tags: database, forms, validation

I would like to ask about a recent black dot of death that is causing crash issues on messaging apps on Android and iOS devices.

More information on this issue can be found in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fepqIO57f8

I would like to know if this issue can cause a potential risk to businesses everywhere if it is inserted to database without the correct validation check? And how do we perform validation check on this because there is a lot of hidden text that is not able to be detected by normal validation I think, such as doing string validation for a text box. It might crash database if the input went through and even making a query will take forever to load because of this issue.

Comment: I'm not willing to click on links like this.  I don't think this is a good question for SO.

Comment: It's just a youtube video explaining how the bug works

Answer (score 0):

well, i dont think you have to worry too much about that black dot, it isnt a virus as far as im aware of in my research about it, this is how it works:
The secret to the message is not actually the black dot, but rather the blank space that comes right after it. When the WhatsApp prank message is converted to HTML, it contains repetitive instances of the "&rlm:" character, which is code for right-to-left text directional formatting.

The right-to-left text format is used for languages such as Arabic and Urdu while the more common left-to-right text format is used for languages such as English. The hidden "&rlm:" code in the black dot prank message instructs WhatsApp to change the direction of the text repeatedly, which requires a lot of processing power.